# Finding unknown exponent

Tags: exponential-function

How do you count the n for this general formula, when you know a, b and c, please?

$a^n + b^n = c^n$  (optional conditions $c<(a+b)<2c$ and $a,b,c ∈ N$ and $n ∉ N$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What do you mean count $n$? do you mean how many values of $n$ exist or  what the value of $n$ is?

Comment: If you want to solve this for $n$, you'll need a numerical method such as Newton-Raphson.

Comment: numerical methods are your best bet.  Also side note , if $a,b,c,n$ are integers then $n=1,2$ as an account of fermats theorem

Comment: perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) might help. You can increase the rate of convergence using halleys method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=c^x-a^x - b^x $$ and numerical methods need to be considered.

In fact, it is better to search for the zero of 
$$g(x)=\log(c^x)-\log(a^x+b^x)=x \log(c)-\log(a^x+b^x)$$ and use Newton method.

To generate a good starting point, you can develop $g(x)$ as a Taylor series built at $x=0$ and get
$$g(x)=-\log (2)+x \left(\log
   (c)-\frac{\log (a)}{2}-\frac{\log (b)}{2}\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this will give, as an *estimate*,
$$x_0=\frac{2 \log (2)}{2 \log (c)-\log (a)-\log (b)}$$

Using, as Ondřej Dvořák did in a comment, $a=5$, $b=7$, $c=10$ and using  either $x_0=0$ or this estimate (which corresponds to the first iteration of Newton method), the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.000000000 \\
 1 & 1.320504044 \\
 2 & 1.370646293 \\
 3 & 1.370715807
\end{array}
\right)$$

You will not have an overshoot of the solution since
$$f(0)=-\log(2) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(0)=-\frac{1}{4} (\log (a)-\log (b))^2 \implies f(0) \times f''(0)>0$$ (refer to Darboux-Fourier theorem).